# Migrating titan-1.0.0 to janusgraph-0.1.1

Tags: titan, janusgraph

I am using titan-1.0.0, I want to migrate it to janusgraph-0.1.1. What are the configuration changes I need to do? I also want to reuse the data which was there for Titan using JanusGraph.

Answer (score 4):

Migration from Titan to JanusGraph is relatively easy. See the [migration documentation](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/migrating-titan.html) and also the [upgrade documentation](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/upgrade.html). The storage format is identical, so you should be able to connect to your existing Titan instance with just configuration updates.

Also, [JanusGraph 0.2.0](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases/tag/v0.2.0) was released recently, and I would recommend that you migrate directly to that release, rather than going with JanusGraph 0.1.1.